# Maven site:deploy (with DIFFERENT url) during "deploy" goal (when in testing profile)?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-site-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

How can I make maven do a site:site and a site:deploy when the deploy is run?

Am I best off to make my own plugin (modified version of maven-release-plugin) or is there an easy way in Maven (configuration of a plugin within a profile)?

Thanks!

EDIT for clarification: I basically want a site-deploy done (to a special url) for snapshot releases. Namely the javadoc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create two profiles.

The first will be active unless a property has been defined. It will use one URL.

The second one will be triggered by some property.

In each profile define the required settings for the site plugin with their respective differences.